# Variable ends up undefined after using $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like an incredibly simple issue but I have no idea why I'm getting undefined. I'm using jQuery to fetch data off a PHP script - specifically a string which the PHP file echoes. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map1;

    $.get("script.php", function(data)
    {
        map1 = data;
    });

    alert(map1);

</script>
```

Now if I alert(map1), it ends up being undefined... why exactly is this the case? I thought by declaring map1 outside $.get, it would fix the problem but that's not the case. If I alert(map1) inside the $.get function, it ends up fine and the variable holds a string (as opposed to being undefined). So the question is... what's going on with map1? And how can I stop it from being undefined / going out of scope / whatever is happening to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. The function passed to `get` is called when the ajax response returns, not immediately.

Comment: I see now... damn, I should have seen that coming, it was quite obvious it was asynchronous. I also fixed the bug (which I had been stressing over for over a week). Thanks to you and others for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Michael has put, the `.get` call is asynchronous so your javascript is executing this call, and then carrying on with your script, which is why you get an `undefined` alert box.

Your best option is to put in a `success` call:

```
$.get("script.php", function(data) 
{ 
    map1 = data; 
})
.success(function() { alert(map1); });
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks for providing me with the success call, this was something I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Because your `alert` is executed before `get` finished. Put right after assignment in function body. `get` initiates the request and returns.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` runs asynchronously, and this is why the function's second parameter is an anonymous function. This anonymous function is invoked once `$.get` has finished executing. `alert(map1)` is invoked immediately, and not asynchronously. You could add the `alert` call to the anonymous function passed to `$.get`:

```
$.get("script.php", function(data){
  map1 = data;
  alert(map1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `$.get` fills the data slower than your alert is executed !
Which means your `$.get` function takes longer to compute than your alert !
You could use `setTimeout()` to work around this but I think its a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing it this way?

```
var map1;

$.ajax({ 
          type: "GET",
          url: "script.php",   
          async: true,
          success : function(data)
          {
               map1 = data;
               alert (data);
          }
});
```